# How to remove duplicate entries within a column row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe
[image]

I want to remove the duplicate entries within a column row and return the unique values only. I tried `set(df['unit])` but it didn't help at all. I want to only have `(New Ward, Adult Ward)/(Pediatric Ward)` for example.
Would you please provide me how to fix this error?

Comment: Your entries look like lists, so you should access each of these lists to convert them to sets to get unique entries.

Comment: You can use pandas drop_duplicates() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your cells contain comma-separated strings. In that case, you can

- split the entries at `',\s*'` (comma plus optional whitespace),
- convert them to sets,
- and rejoin them to comma-delimited strings:

```py
df['unit'] = df.unit.str.split(',\s*').apply(set).str.join(', ')
```

**However,** there are downsides to this way of encoding values. (For example, `'Adult Ward, New WARD'` and `'New WARD, Adult Ward'` would be two distinct values when in reality, they are identical). Consider handling each ward as a separate column, e.g.,

```py
for w in ['Pediatric Ward', 'New Ward', 'Adult Ward']:
    df[w] = df.unit.str.contains(w, case=False)
```

will result in separate columns for each ward, which will be much easier to work with down the line, like getting combinations of wards:

```py
                   unit  Pediatric Ward  New Ward  Adult Ward
0        Pediatric Ward            True     False       False
1  Adult Ward, New WARD           False      True        True
2              New WARD           False      True       False
3        Pediatric Ward            True     False       False
4  Adult Ward, New WARD           False      True        True
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, @fsimonjetz! For the `"WARD"` issue, I cope with it by adding cleaning step. `df['unit']=df['unit'].replace({"WARD", "Ward"}, regex=True)`